# Simple combinatorics question with different interpretations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Doing some combinatorics exercises and it all went well until i stumbled upon this question.

> You are doing an exam, and you get $20$ questions, and $20$ answers. You are supposed to combine the questions and answers. What is the probability of getting it all right?

Now here my thinking pattern goes like this. I obviously have $20$ questions, that need to be matched. If i start with the first question i have $20$ answers to match it with, the second has $19$ and it continues like that down to $1$. Therefore i suppose there are $20!$ different combinations, and only $1$ has the right answer. Therefore the right answer would be $P(A)=\frac{1}{20!}$ Does this seem right to you? Or would you solve the question another way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, the probability is $1/20!$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, and here is an attempt at an explanation.

If one has to get all the questions right, then at each step we must have matched the question with the correct answer, so for the first question, we have a 1/20 chance of matching the question with the correct answer. We don't have to worry about what happens the other 19/20 times because if we get the first one wrong, then we did not get all of the questions matched up correctly. So we go onto the next question, and now we only have 19 possibilities. This pattern continues and thus the answer is as you stated $\frac{1}{20!}$